# Sum a specific range of elements of a multi-dimension array

Tags: vba, excel

How can I sum a specific range of elements of a multi-dimension array without using a `For... Next`statement?

I know how to do it with a 1-dimension array. For example, the next code:

```
Dim GRMORT(1 to 864) As Double
Dim PSUM as Double
PSUM = Application.Sum(Application.Index(GRMORT, 1, Evaluate("ROW(100:200")")))
```

return the sum of the 100th to 200th elements. However, if I use a 2-dimension array:

```
Dim GRMORT(1 to 864, 1 to 24) As Double
```

the function doesn't work. I thought it had to be with the second argument of the `Index` function, so I tried change it to `2`, `3`, ... But that wasn't the solution.

How can I change the `Index`function to get the sum of the 100th to 200th elements of the fourth column (or any other column)?

Comment: You can use index to slice out the 4th column so you have a 1 dimensional array. Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr,0,4)  I think if 1 based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just supply the column argument:

```
Dim GRMORT(1 To 864, 1 To 5) As Double
Dim PSUM As Double
PSUM = Application.Sum(Application.Index(GRMORT, Evaluate("ROW(100:200)"), 4))
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you need to do this in a loop you should note using `index()` the performance is not good - a loop over your array is much faster.

Comment: @Tim Williams, thanks for the advice. However, because the small size of the array, the difference between the two methods is not relevant.